# Auto layout for UITableViewCell with ratio imageView

Tags: ios, uitableview, autolayout

I have an imageView with height = 0.5 * width & pin 4 edges to cell.contentView.
How to cell auto fit height to imageView height.

For example:

```
iPhone5 : cell size = image size = 320 x 160
iPhone6+: cell size = image size = 414 x 207
```

Comment: Have you tried something that's not working?  What you're asking isn't completely clear, but either more explicitly showing what you want to happen or providing more detail on what you've tried so far which isn't working, would provide better insight to the problem.

Comment: can u post the screen shots what u want to acheive

Answer (score 0):

You can set aspect ratio constraint to your UIImageView with properly multiplier in InterfaceBuilder. And use this code for calculating cell height:

```
self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44.0; //your estimated height
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to implement -

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
CGFloat screenWidth = screenRect.size.width;
CGFloat screenHeight = screenRect.size.height;

  return screenWidth*0.5 ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are using pins that is constraints for layout of the image view, changing the frame at the runtime won't change it's frame. You can follow below steps to change the frame at the runtime:

- Set the height and width of the `UIImageView` required for iPhone 6+ (considering that iPhone 6+ is the highest resolution supported).
- Take the `IBOutlet` of both the constraints.
- In `awakeFromNib` method of your tableview cell's class, you can set the value of both the constraints using `[constraintInstance setConstant:valueForTheConstraint]`.

Or you can try to set the aspect ratio for the height and width of the image view.

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
        return [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width/2 ;
}
```